# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered

Tags: frequency, pyaudio

I'm trying to make my Philips hue lights change colors based on the **Hz** of a played song. But i faced a **RuntimeWarning** and can't figure out whats going on. I'd highly appreciate it if anyone could help me out here :)

```py
 wf = wave.open('visualize.wav', 'rb')
swidth = wf.getsampwidth()
RATE = wf.getframerate()
window = np.blackman(chunk)
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
channels = wf.getnchannels()
stream = p.open(format =
                p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels = channels,
                rate = RATE,
                output = True)

data = wf.readframes(chunk)
print('switdth {} chunk {} data {} ch {}'.format(swidth,chunk,len(data), channels))

while len(data) == chunk*swidth*channels:
    stream.write(data)
    indata = np.fromstring(data, dtype='int16')
    channel0 = indata[0::channels]
    fftData=abs(np.fft.rfft(indata))**2
    which = fftData[1:].argmax() + 1
    if which != len(fftData)-1:
        y0,y1,y2 = np.log(fftData[which-1:which+2:])
        x1 = (y2 - y0) * .5 / (2 * y1 - y2 - y0)
        thefreq = (which+x1)*RATE/chunk
        print ("The freq is %f Hz." % (thefreq))

    elif thefreq > 4000:
        for i in cycle(color_list):
            change_light_color(room, *color_list[i])
            time.sleep(0.5)

    else:
        if thefreq < 4000:
            for i in cycle(color_list_2):
                change_light_color(room, *color_list_2[i])
                time.sleep(0.5)
if data:
    stream.write(data)
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

**This is what i end up with:**

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/Sem/Desktop/hue_visualizer/visualize.py
Sem@Sems-MacBook-Pro hue_visualizer % /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/Sem/Desktop/hue_visualizer/visualize.py
switdth 2 chunk 1024 data 4096 ch 2
/Users/Sem/Desktop/hue_visualizer/visualize.py:69: DeprecationWarning: The binary mode of fromstring is deprecated, as it behaves surprisingly on unicode inputs. Use frombuffer instead
  indata = np.fromstring(data, dtype='int16')
/Users/Sem/Desktop/hue_visualizer/visualize.py:74: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  y0,y1,y2 = np.log(fftData[which-1:which+2:])
/Users/Sem/Desktop/hue_visualizer/visualize.py:75: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  x1 = (y2 - y0) * .5 / (2 * y1 - y2 - y0)
The freq is nan Hz.
The freq is nan Hz.
The freq is nan Hz.
The freq is nan Hz.
The freq is nan Hz.
```